# asp.net showing a box with a ok button when a link is clicked

Tags: c#, html, asp.net

I have an asp.net site where i want a link lets say: "Click here for the telephone number"

And when the user clicks the link, a box should be shown with the information, just like the box used with this button:

```
<asp:Button ID="Button1" runat="server" Text="Button" OnClientClick = "return alert('Are you sure you want to delete?');"/>
```

But the box shows a OK and Cancel button - so is there any way to only show the Ok button? and use it in a linkbutton.

EDIT:

Okay, the code above actually shows the OK button only, but it seems like when i press the OK button a postback is made, how can i prevent this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Replace your following attribute

```
OnClientClick="return alert('Are you sure you want to delete?');"
```

With

```
OnClientClick="alert('Are you sure you want to delete?'); return false;"
```

Answer (score 2):

In the script the **alert** should be **confirm**.

Comment: but the confirm box shows the ok and cancel button.. now i just want to stop the postback for when i click the ok button - is that possible?

Comment: alert, afaik, does not return a value. Instead try

alert(""); return false;

The return true should stop the link, but this would always stop the  link - even if the user does want to delete.

Answer (score 0):

Okay the solution was:

```
<asp:LinkButton runat="server" ID="LinkButton1" Font-Size="Small" OnClientClick ="if(alert('Text here!')) return false;" CausesValidation="false">Click Here</asp:LinkButton>
```